# template strings inside if statements

Tags: javascript

is it correct syntax to use string literals inside if statements. please guide. how can i use categ dynamically in the function based on different values so that i dont have to write the same function for every button clicked.

```
const filterButtons= document.querySelectorAll(".filter-btn")

 let categ;

 filterButtons.forEach(function (btn) {
       
      
       

       btn.addEventListener("click",function (e) {
       if(e.currentTarget.dataset.id=="price") {
         categ = "price";
         console.log(categ);
       } 
       
       if(e.currentTarget.dataset.id=="discountPercentage") {
        categ = "discountPercentage";
        console.log(categ);
      }

      if(e.currentTarget.dataset.id=="rating") {
        categ = "rating";
        console.log(categ);
      }

    
      let newModData = [...mainProducts];

        let i=0;
        let j=0;
        let fixed = 0
        
        
     while(j< newModData.length-1) {
     
     while(i< newModData.length-1)
       {
         if(`newModData[i+1].${categ}`< `newModData[fixed].${categ}`)
           {
            const temp = Object.assign({}, newModData[fixed]);
            
            newModData[fixed] = newModData[i+1];
            newModData[i+1] = temp;
           }   
         i++;
     
       }
       i=j+1;
       fixed++;
       j++; 
     }   
     
     displayNew(newModData);  

       })
```

is it correct syntax to use string literals inside if statements. please guide. how can i use categ dynamically in the function based on different values so that i dont have to write the same function for every button clicked.

Comment: This code is painfull to read. What are you trying to do with these loops? To me it looks like you're trying to sort `newModData` by `categ`? `asc`ending or `desc`ending?

Comment: oh my bad. let me explain. filters buttons are element variable of the buttons sort by price , sort by percentage and sort by rating respectively. i aim to sort array of objects by the dataset value of the indiviual button. e.g if the user presses sort by price then the array of objects will be sorted by price and if the user presses sort by rating then the array will be sorted by rating. so what is wish to know is it possible to use string literals inside if statements. is it correct syntax.. can i address individual array items dynamically

Comment: you could do something like `const newModData = [...mainProducts].sort((a,b) => a[categ] < b[categ] ? -1 : a[categ] > b[categ] ? 1 : 0);` without the template literals and the loops etc.

Answer (score 1):

If `newModData` is an array of objects, then the correct syntax is:

```js
if(newModData[i+1][categ] < newModData[fixed][categ]) {
 // Your logic here
}
```

To access properties of an object dynamically you must use brackets `[]` instead of dot `.`:

```js
const prop = "name"; //

const someObj = {
  name: "Jane",
  age: 20
}

console.log(someObj[prop]); // --> Jane
```